# Get random field from Rest Assured Json response with multiple items

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

Migrating from Ruby to Java, i need to parse and get one field randomly from a multiple item response.

This is my ApiCall method that i use to get my response:

```
        Response response = given().
            headers(this.headers).
            params(this.body).
        when().
            post(this.url).
        then().
            contentType(ContentType.JSON).
            statusCode(200).
        extract().
            response();
```

And it give me this JSON structure:

```
{
  "Contents": {
    "Title": "Search results",
    "Count": "10",
    "Page": "1",
    "TotalCount": "1",
    "TotalPages": 2,
    "Genres": [
      "Genre_1",
      "Genre_2",
      "Genre_3"
    ],
    "Contents": [
      {
        "title": "content1_title",
        "original_text": "original text 1",
        "full_text": "Sample full sized text 1",
        "short_text": "Sample short text 1",
        "children_ids": {
          "item": [
            1,
            2
          ]
        },
        "children_uuids": {
          "item": [
            "item1_uuid",
            "item2_uuid"
          ]
        },
        "parent_ids": {
          "item": [
            1
          ]
        },
        "parent_uuids": {
          "item": [
            "item1_uuid"
          ]
        },
        "aired_from": "1994-01-01",
        "aired_to": "1994-12-31",
        "tags": {
          "item": [
            ""
          ]
        },
        "available_condition1": 0,
        "available_condition2": 1,
        "price_condition1": "0.00",
        "price_condition2": "13.00"
      },
      {
        "title": "content2_title",
        "original_text": "original text 2",
        "full_text": "Sample full sized text 2",
        "short_text": "Sample short text 2",
        "children_ids": {
          "item": [
            1,
            2
          ]
        },
        "children_uuids": {
          "item": [
            "item1_uuid",
            "item2_uuid"
          ]
        },
        "parent_ids": {
          "item": [
            1
          ]
        },
        "parent_uuids": {
          "item": [
            "item1_uuid"
          ]
        },
        "aired_from": "1998-01-01",
        "aired_to": "1998-01-31",
        "tags": {
          "item": [
            ""
          ]
        },
        "available_condition1": 0,
        "available_condition2": 1,
        "price_condition1": "0.00",
        "price_condition2": "13.00"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Success": true
}
```

The thing is that i need to get a random "title" field that has at least one "children_uuids" from the total ammount of the ones in the response.

So as i understand, the steps are:

1) get the total size of "Contents.Contents" items.
2) get a random number between 0 and the total amount of items.
3) use that number to select one item with the "Contents.Contents.[n].title" format or similar.

Tried the following with no success:

```
        JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(response.toString());
        List<?> list = jsonPath.getList("Contents.Contents.title.flatten()");
        System.out.println(list);
```

That gives me the following error:

```
io.restassured.path.json.exception.JsonPathException: Failed to parse the JSON document
```

For reference, in Ruby the code will be:

```
            amount = @result['api_response']['Contents']['Contents'].count
            amount = amount - 1
            a = rand(0..amount)
            while @result['api_response']['Contents']['Contents'][a]['children_uuids']['item'].nil? do
                a = rand(0..amount)
                #children_uuids = $result['api_response']['Contents']['Contents'][a]['children_uuids']
            end
            #price_hd = @result['api_response']['Contents']['Contents'][a]['price_hd']
            content_title = @result['api_response']['Contents']['Contents'][a]['title']
```

UPDATE: I've got it working partially... i've found a way to select one item from the list with this line:

```
String contentTitle = response.then().extract().path("Contents.Contents[0].title");
```

But can't find a way to use this jsonpath

```
String contentTitle = response.then().extract().path("Contents.Contents.[?(@.children_uuids)].uuid");
```

That second line give me:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Invalid JSON expression:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: [ @ line 1, column 45.
   nRootObject.Contents.Contents.[?(@.child
                                 ^
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I've found a solution with the following code:

```
            // get random content data
            Integer contentAmmount = response.body().path("Contents.Contents.size()");
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(contentAmmount);
            while (response.body().path(
                    String.join("", "Contents.Contents[", Integer.toString(randomInt), 
                            "].children_uuids.item")).toString().isEmpty() ) {
                randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(contentAmmount);
            }

            String contentTitle = response.then().extract()
                    .path(String.join("", "Contents.Contents[", Integer.toString(randomInt), "].title"));
            String contentUuid = response.then().extract()
                    .path(String.join("", "Contents.Contents[", Integer.toString(randomInt), "].uuid"));
            String contentChildrenUuid = response.body().path(
                    String.join("", "Contents.Contents[", Integer.toString(randomInt), 
                            "].children_uuids.item"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is very difficult to do in REST-assured, and perhaps even Java for that matter.

Can I suggest you take a look at [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) (disclaimer: am dev). So you can call into a JavaScript function to generate a random number, assign that to a variable and then form a path expression to do exactly what you want:

```
Feature:

Scenario:

* def data = read('data.json')
* def size = (data.Contents.Contents.length)
* def index = Math.floor(Math.random() * size)
* print 'selected index: ' + index
* def item = (data.Contents.Contents[index])
* def children_uuids = item.children_uuids
* match children_uuids == { item: ['item1_uuid', 'item2_uuid'] }
```